# yii not showing with this $model->errors code - using composite primary key

Tags: yii

hello friends i am using composite primary key in my yii application and i am trying to import csv file into database using save() function and i have only three rows but when i am trying to import those only one row getting insert not all. and if i am trying to access the error then nothing is showing .. but when using model->validate then it returning false.

```
CVarDumper::dump($model->errors,10,
CVarDumper::dump($model->attributes, 10, true);
CVarDumper::dump($model->validate(), 10, true);
```

what should i use to print error .. above three are not able to print error. but error is their.

regards
anil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before validating you do not have any errors, because you haven't checked for anything, validate your model and after that you can catch your errors

```
$model->validate();
var_dump($model->errors);
```